# how to get the second table values in one to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I have two Models

TermOne

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TermOne extends Model
{
    public function term_one_files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TermOneFile');
    }
}
```

I want to get values of this Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TermOneFile extends Model
{
    public function term_ones()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TermOne');
    }
    
}
```

I want to get the table two values TermOneFile form TermOne with eager loading but I get this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'term_one_files.term_one_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from term_one_files where term_one_files.term_one_id in (1))

here is my Controller

```
$curriculum = TermOne::with('term_one_files')->where('id', $request->curriculum_id)->get();

 dd($curriculum);

return view('backend.uploads.index', compact('grade', 'subject', 'term_id', 'curriculum'));
```

maybe Im doing something wrong

term_one_files structure

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('term_one_files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('curriculum_id');
            $table->string('filename')->nullable();
            $table->string('filepath')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('curriculum_id')->references('id')->on('term_ones')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Comment: How is the structure of the `term_one_files` DB table?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I have uploaded it above

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your foreign key in the relationship this way:

```
public function term_one_files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TermOneFile', 'curriculum_id');
}
```

or you can change your column name in the migration file from: 'curriculum_id' to 'term_one_id'.